# Empty the results of PDO DB query inside foreach method

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop

Im trying to create a method, which can take any number of arguments / parameters. The first and only required parameter contains the value of a database query. The additional arguments passed matches the columns inside a table. 
The arguments should then be used inside a foreach loop to retrieve the data from the database by means of the query and column names which were passed as arguments. For this I use the `func_get_args()` build in PHP function...

Here is an example

```
class Crud{
    public $results;

 function selectAllJobs(){
        $sql="SELECT * from jobs";
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();
        return $stmnt->fetchAll();
    }

function displayResults($results){
        $this->results = $results;
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";

        $arg_list = func_get_args();

        foreach ($results as $index=> $result) {
           echo $currentParam = $arg_list[$index];
             echo $result[$currentParam];
             echo'<br />';
        }

$obj = new Crud();
$results = $obj->selectAllJobs();
$obj->displayResults($results, 'location', 'description', 'headline');
```

The Idea of the methods inside the class is so that you can easily query database by simply calling the method, and then easily display the results of the query by simply calling the method `displayResults()` hope that makes sense....Any help / advice appreciated.

**TABLE**

[image]

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: @kunruh IM getting undefined & string offset errors when running `displayResults()` The `selectAll()` method should perform the DB query. An array will be returned that array must get passed to `displayResult()` where the array is looped over displaying the result...hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You pass in 4 parameters as arguments which including `$results` into `displayResults()` instead of 3 parameters, this break your `foreach` loop because the first index is not `'location'` that you wish for, but the `$results`. You can `print_r($arg_list)` to see yourself.

You don't need to return `$stmt->fetchAll()` at `selectAllJobs()` and pass into `displayResults()` again. The results can be kept within the class (and private) by assigning it to `$this-results`.

You also need two `foreach` loops, one for looping through the `$this-results`, and another for looping through the `$arg_list`. So here is the code:

```
class Crud
{
    private $results;
    private $db;

    function selectAllJobs()
    {
        $sql="SELECT * from jobs";
        $stmnt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();
        $this->results=$stmnt->fetchAll();
    }

    function displayResults()
    {
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";

        $arg_list = func_get_args();

        foreach ($this->results as $result) {
            foreach ($arg_list as $index=>$value) {
              echo $result[$index];
              echo'<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Crud();
$obj->selectAllJobs();
$obj->displayResults('location', 'description', 'headline');
```